# Is Frost Moon Terraria even possible to beat in time?

Tags: terraria

I already have post Moonlord gear including the Meowmere (which I have found extremely useful for taking out many weaker enemies in the earlier waves), and the Terrarian which I use against the bosses for it's high DPS. But it still wasnt enough.

The only guides I can find online are just general boss strategies like "use campfires/heart lanterns", but dying isn't the issue.

And all of the discussion boards are several years old and talk about "reaching wave 15", but unlike the pumpkin moon, there is apparently 20 now. I can consistently reach 15 or 16 by the end of the night, but always run out of time, and I don't see how it's even possible to reach wave 20 in time.

Is it even intended to be possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By the looks of [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J-HWtu01zds), yes. Towards the end is where they manage to finish it.

The poster of that video tried a few strategies, but it seems the one they went with that allowed them to beat all 20 waves was setting up a [sky bridge](https://terraria-archive.fandom.com/wiki/Skybridge#:%7E:text=A%20Skybridge%20can%20be%20constructed,map%20or%20the%20desired%20location.) and using the [Zenith](https://terraria.fandom.com/wiki/Zenith) sword as their main weapon of choice, among other things.

They originally tried a few other things, such as an arena with traps, but trap damage caused the NPC's to be momentarily invincible, lowering your overall DPS, making it very hard to finish all 20 waves.

Answer (score 4):

Getting to wave 20 in frost moon is mostly about being able to kill ice queens quickly enough. Because they tend to fly offscreen, this means either a long range homing weapon to hit them while they're out sight, or mobility to chase them down.

Personally, I've had the best results with SDMG, chlorophyte bullets and vortex armor in stealth mode - but you have to shoot blindly, and if a boss health bar appears, keep shooting in that direction. You will kill most santanks and everscreams before you can even see them for faster progression, and make quick work of ice queens too. Use an antigravity hook to get some mobility while stealthed.

I can also get there with a terraprisma summoner build and zenith, and chasing the enemies down in an UFO mount, but find it a bit slower.

Also, for the record, wave 20 is infinite, you will be fighting endless bosses until morning, so you cannot really "beat" frost moon. And it has had 20 waves forever, but 15 waves is what you need to get the achievement and to get christmas, so most people care about 15 waves. :)

Comment: To add to this, in addition to a proper armor and weapons, potions are extremely helpful in buffing damage and keeping the player alive. You'll just need to go through the effort of gathering ingredients and crafting.

Comment: No. Its 20 for both the achievement and to initiate Christmas

Comment: According to the wiki, it's 15 for PC, Console and Mobile, and 20 for 3DS and some old mobile/console versions. I have verified yesterday that wave 20 is not needed for Christmas on PC. https://terraria.fandom.com/wiki/Frost_Moon
It might be useful to indicate the platform you're playing on in the question. :)